# Updating Juno to Kepler cause existing project in workspace non functional

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

does any one know how to over come from this issue ?
I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337526/how-to-upgrade-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-from-juno-to-kepler) but after updating it, every thing seems to correct but my existing projects are not able to run via tomcat (previously in juno it was working). I can see my tomcat server under servers view, when I click on **File** menu -> New it show **No Applicable Item**.. I am not even able to create new Dynamic web project, neither I am able to change my project facets from project properties...
Can any one help me out in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337692/429972

I always do a clean new install and get the plugins I need again. It doesnt take very long usually.

After you have done that import your old projects in a new workspace.

Comment: isn't there any way to recover it ?

Comment: seriously.. obtaining fresh new copy is much more comfortable