# Eclipse upgrade juno to kepler. Eclipse wont start

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

Hi i tried to upgrade my eclipse using like this.
[How to upgrade Eclipse for Java EE Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337526/how-to-upgrade-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers-from-juno-to-kepler)
But now my Eclipse start and close. I tried clean start. 
I don't want to install clean 4.3 because i have to much settings and plugins to migrate.

At the moment i am working on clean 4.3 with copied old plugins folder but it sometimes closing automatically when building workspace.
I would prefer to resurrect old eclipse because i have to much things to configure and it will take a lot of time to do that. I will try working on new one but i would be glad to resurrect old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have eclipse.ini

> -Xms2048m
>   -Xmx512m
>   Kelpler will crash on start. Juno is working with this settings.
>   But when we have lower eclipse.ini. Eclipse is starting.
>
> -Xms512m
>   -Xmx512m
>   The only problem left is to how force Kepler to dont crash -Xms bigger than 512m
>   (I have 8gb of ram)
>   And 512m is to small for me to build workspace :/

EDIT Solution is also increase Xmx to 2048