# how to upgrade from juno to kepler for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE juno , I need to upgrade my eclipse to kepler for developing J2EE applications, in my IDE help menu i tried to install new software and i also added kepler related download site , then it installed some updates after I restarted my laptop but it is not showing me option for developing J2EE applications. Help me please, without installing the complete eclipse ide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade Eclipse for Java EE Developers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337526/how-to-upgrade-eclipse-for-java-ee-developers)

Answer (score 0):

Both Juno and Kepler are separate eclipse IDE hence you need separate installation for Eclipse Kepler and keep your original juno installer. You can download it from [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php)